# $urlRouterProvider.when keeps reloading state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have just added nested states to my `AngularJS` application, but I also wanted to add a reroute if the parent state was hit, so I added this code to my `UI-router`

```
angular.module('app')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/PDGODSTD', '/PDGODSTD/weekinfo');

        $stateProvider.state('PDGODSTD', {
            //abstract: true, // uncommenting this resolves in an error telling me that I can't navigate to an abstract state
            url: "/PDGODSTD",
            templateUrl: '../Modules/PDGODSTD/web/index.html'
        })
        .state('PDGODSTD.weekinfo', {
            url: "/weekinfo",
            templateUrl: '../Modules/PDGODSTD/web/weekinfo/weekinfo.html',
            controller: 'PDGODSTDweekinfoController',
            resolve: {
            }
        })
    });
```

index.html file only contains this piece of code `<ui-view><ui-view />`

What happens is that the router keep rerouting back and fourth between the parent state and the nested state, or so it seems in my debugger in `Chrome`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple plunker seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/8O7YZY9vBsCW0Wbj6ygU?p=preview

Check if your templateUrl are fetching properly (check network tab).

In ui-router 1.0.0-rc.1 the preferred mechanism to redirect is to use `redirectTo:`.
The docs for `redirectTo` are here: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#redirectto

```
    $stateProvider.state('PDGODSTD', {
        redirectTo: 'PDGODSTD.weekinfo',
        url: "/PDGODSTD",
        templateUrl: '../Modules/PDGODSTD/web/index.html'
    })
    .state('PDGODSTD.weekinfo', {
        url: "/weekinfo",
        templateUrl: '../Modules/PDGODSTD/web/weekinfo/weekinfo.html',
        controller: 'PDGODSTDweekinfoController',
        resolve: {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Didn't fix my problem, but helped me get on the right path :-D

Answer (score 0):

The error was in my `index.html` file. The end tag was wrong it should have been `<ui-view></ui-view>` rather than `<ui-view><ui-view />`

Chris' answer is set as the correct one since he showed me that the error wasn't in the logic but somewhere else

Comment: side note: it would be nice if angular validated stuff like that for us :)  `<ui-view/>` seems to be parsed as `<ui-view>` (no closing tag) and angular forgives us for that.  But if you do `<ui-view/><ui-view/>` it gets completely confused